# Making a pledge to Allah?

Tags: allah

Could you make a pledge to Allah, that if He grants your wish, then you would have to give to charity or fast for a certain amount of days?

I heard people do this and tell me it works.

Answer (score 1):

### **This is called Nathr or vow**

**And it has two main types**, good and bad.

The one **you ask about is the bad type**, and the Prophet PBUH (ﷺ) ordered us **not to do it**:

> Abu Heraira reported    Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying:  Do not take
>   vows, for a vow has no effect against Fate; it is only from the
>   miserly that something is extracted.
>
> [Sahih Muslim 1640 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/26/7)

The problem in this type is that as if  one haggles Allah (says if you Allah do this for me I will do that and that) do you think Allah needs anything from him or from any one?!, and the prophet said that will not change fate.

The good vow is when one intends to do some good without conditions.

Last thing to mention that Nathr becomes mandatory if it is something permissible, there are other details related to this subject of vows, but I believe the above answers your question.

**Updates:**

Not to confuse you, the mentioned vows (Nathr) in Quran as the above answer's update indicates are all of the good type, which Prophets did, they did not make it conditional.

Answer (score 1):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

In regards to your interesting question, of note, what you inquired (regarding pledge) seems to be related to Nazr (vow). So, at the first stage, I recommend you to read the following related issue which can demonstrate its value as an Islamic order/recommendation:

> **Nazr: A Vow with Allah**;
>
> Imam Hasan (a) and Imam Husain (a) were still very young probably in
>   their fifth to sixth year of age. Once,
>   both of them fell sick and their parents, Imam Ali (a) and Bibi Fatima
>   (a) were grieved to see them in unhealthy condition.
>
> The Holy Prophet Prophet Muhammad (S) came to see them. He loved them
>   very much and on seeing them sick, he also was much grieved. They all
>   prayed for their quick recovery. The Holy Prophet suggested to the
>   parents to keep a Nazr for the restoration of the health of the
>   children. Thereupon. Imam Ali (a) and Bibi Fatima (a) made a Nazr (a
>   vow) that they would fast three days upon the recovery of the
>   children. Allah accepted their prayers and granted their Nazr. Both the children
>   recovered from their illness. Imam Ali (a) and Bibi Fatima (a) decided
>   to fast in fulfilment of the Nazr...
>
> (The complete text:
>   https://www.al-islam.org/islamic-stories/nazr-vow-allah-be-fulfilled)

In order to have more information about your inquiry, I suggest you to evaluate/peruse the following relevant issues which can clarify the matter a lot:

Vow (Nazr) (which, here, can be regarded as what you called as Pledge):

> Issue 2649: * Vow means making it obligatory upon oneself to do some
>   good act, or to refrain from doing an act which it is better not to
>   do, for the sake of, or for the pleasure of Allah.
>
> Issue 2650: While making a vow, a formula declaration has to be
>   pronounced, though is not necessary that it should be in Arabic. If a
>   person says: “When the patient recovers from his ailment, it will be
>   obligatory upon me to pay $10 to a poor man, for the sake of Allah,”
>   his vow will be in order.
>
> Issue 2651: * It is necessary that the person making a vow is baligh
>   and sane, and makes the vow with free will and intention. If he has
>   been coerced to make a vow, or if he makes it owing to excitement,
>   without any intention or choice, his vow is not in order.
>
> Issue 2652: * If a person who is feeble-minded, (i.e. one who
>   squanders his property for useless purposes) makes a vow, for example,
>   to give something to poor, his vow is not in order. Similarly, if a
>   bankrupt person makes a vow to pay from the wealth over which he has
>   no right of disposal or discretion, the vow will not be valid.
>
> ... To read the complete issues, read the source of the answer (below answer):

**Conclusion:** Consequently, you can do Nazr (or vow, which can be a kind of pledge), and afterwards you should do/perform what you vowed (if Allah granted that) based on its condition.

---

**Update:**

The issue of Nadhr, from the viewpoint of Qur'an (as the most significant Islamic source) has mentioned, too. E.g.:

> Nadhr is a tradition which has been practiced by all divine prophets
>   (a) and previous nations and in Islam, it has been legitimate and
>   practiced. The glorious Qur'an has mentioned the story of the nadhr of
>   'Imran's wife, Maryam's mother, and says, "When the wife of 'Imran
>   said, 'My Lord, I dedicate to You what is in my belly, in
>   consecration. Accept it from me; indeed You are the All-hearing, the
>   All-knowing." (Qur'an 3:35)
>
> And the Sura Maryam, after narrating the story of Prophet 'Isa (a),
>   God the Almighty tells Lady Maryam (a) that when you see any person
>   (with sign language) say to them, "Indeed I have vowed a fast to the
>   All-beneficent, so I will not speak to any human today." (Qur'an
>   19:24)
>
> The Qur'an, when mentioning one of the attributes of true servants of
>   God, says, “  "They fulfill their vows and fear a day whose ill will be
>   widespread." (Qur'an 76:7)

And so on.

And Allah knows best.

---

**Source(s):**

- https://www.al-islam.org/islamic-laws-ayatullah-ali-al-husayni-al-sistani/vow-and-covenant
- http://en.wikishia.net/view/Nadhr

Answer (score -2):

AssalamoAlaikum

Yes Asking to Allah is very normal, i do the same but Apart from Allah it's Sin.
Belief in Islam means (Arabic sentences just writing their points)
Belief in

1) Allah

2) Allah's Angels

3) Allah's Books

4) Allah's Prophets

5) End Of World

6) Whatever happens in our life, happens with Allah's choice and it's always good for us

7)The day of judgement.
(Allah forgive me if I am making any mistake)

In point 6, it is hinted that if it is good for you it will be accepted, sometimes we think that what is good in present for us but we don't know it may be bad for our future...so Allah decide the best way.

Last part we should keep praying/pledging if it is not accepted here, Allah promises to give us Sawab (reward) on the Day of Judgement.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question.